# Why is there not enough CP violation to account for baryogenesis in the SM?

Tags: standard-model, big-bang, cp-violation, baryons, baryogenesis

One of Sakharov conditions states that both C and CP symmetries must be violated by a theory which includes any baryogenesis mechanism. The Standard Model happens to be such a theory, and happens to have both C and CP violation (other than satisfying the other Sakharov conditions). Now, it is "well known" that the CP violation in the electroweak sector is not large enough to produce the observed baryon to antybarion asymmetry:

$\eta = \frac{n_B-n_{\bar{B}}}{n_B+n_{\bar{B}}} \simeq \frac{n_B}{n_\gamma} = 6.1\times10^{-10}$

where the measurement comes from [this WMAP paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0302207).

My question is: how do we quantify the disagreement between this measured quantity and the CP violation in the SM? The only plausible explanation I managed to find comes from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4186.pdf) (Eq. 13) and can be summarised saying that

$\frac{D}{T_{sph}^{12}} \sim 10^{-20} \ll \eta$

where $T_{sph}$ is the sphaleron temperature and $D$ is the Jarlskog determinant.

Is this the only estimate that we currently have or are there more quantitative arguments regarding this problem?

Comment: This issue a common point of confusion, for me too.  From what I know, baryogenesis implies CP violation, but the converse may not be true.  The CP violation in the Standard Model relates to a complex phase in the CKM matrix, but no term in the Lagrangian changes baryon number.

Comment: You are right, in the sense that baryogenesis *requires* CP violation as one of three necessary (but not sufficient) conditions - and not vice versa, of course. But it is quite common to find in literature mentions of how CP violation in the SM is not large enough to explain the baryon-antybarion asymmetry. I could never understand whether there is proof (i.e. if someone actually calculated the theoretical value for eta) or it's just a "feeling" (i.e. a back-of-the-envelope estimate like the one I mentioned).